# Вывести элементы многомерного ассоциативного массива php

Tags: php, массивы

У меня есть вот такой массив. Я хочу вывести в строку полное имя (Piter Parker) и отдельно его 'rate'. А то пробую проверять через is_array и далее выводить. В случаи с 1(подмассивом в массиве 'owners') еще получается, но так как их 2(а может быть и больше) выводит или Null или Array

```
$tasks = [
    [
        'taskID' => '01',
        'taskTitle' => 'Design',
        'owners' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Piter',
            'surname' => 'Parker',
            'rate' => 'middle',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Bart',
            'surname' => 'Simpson',
            'rate' => 'junior',
        ]
],
```

// далее аналогичный блок в массиве

Comment: А как вы его пытаетесь вывести, где код?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($tasks as $task){ //проходим по всем заданиям (первый уровень масива)
    foreach ($task['owners'] as $owner){ // проходим по всем исполнителям (второй уровень масива)
         echo $owner['name'] . ' ' . $owner['surname']; // выводим имя и фамилию
         echo '<br/>';
         echo $owner['rate']; // выводим статус
    }
}
```

Comment: Ключи в кавычках же.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Не прикрепил свой код (затупил). Делал похожим способом, не додумался во втором foreach прописать $task['owners']. Писал просто $task as $owner